# This modeling improves the performance of the DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I could table that make this way

```
CREATE TABLE product {
    id int not null,
    name varchar(60),
    keywords varchar(150),
    meta_desc varchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
}
```

So I do a select as:

```
SELECT name FROM product;
```

But I will not always need of keywords or descriptions goal in my select , thinking , it would be better to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE product {
    id int not null,
    name varchar(60),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
}

CREATE TABLE description {
    id int not null,
    keywords varchar(150),
    meta_desc varchar(150),
    product_id int not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_prod FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id)
}
```

Both situation produce the same result , but there is some that best choice modeling ?

Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you use "select name from product" when you don't need all fields?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  Please use more words and maybe we can understand what it is you want to know.

Comment: Standard normalization rules should be applied first, can a product have many keywords and descriptions?

Comment: It is exactly what #lulco quoted. It is better to create a table containing all the fields (name, description, meta description), or create two tables where the other would be to contain the descriptions, since not need them at all times.

Ok, a select name product as an example know that solves the case, but in modeling issues, it would not be better?

Answer (score 0):

Performance is controlled by inserting an index only. The `not null` just is a constraint that prevents entering nil data here. If `product_id` is optional you should not supply it since it forces it being non optional.